# Cannot browse phpMyAdmin table: Error #1038 - Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Trying to view a very old MyISAM table in phpMyAdmin, it fails with SQL error:

> #1038 - Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size

I presume phpMyAdmin is running a `SELECT * FROM my_table` here.

However, **if I copy the table (structure and data), the copied table can be viewed no problem**. I'm looking for some guidance as to what might be causing the error on the original table and why making a straight copy sorts the issue out.

Comment: [How to Check MyISAM Tables for Errors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/myisam-check.html)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've checked and repaired, no change.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert myISAM db to InnoDB so that you can get away from that error.

Hope this [link](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/convert-myisam-to-innodb/) will help you.

Comment: I found this option from my research, hope this will fix it.